# How to change language of MDN documentation in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, documentation

I'm using the Visual Studio Code editor and its built-in CSS Intellisense extension for HTML, which provides MDN documentation on hovering over CSS classes and selectors. However, I've noticed that the displayed MDN reference is currently in English, and I'd like to know if there's a way to switch it to another language (e.g., Chinese).

I tried to look up the issue, but it was not resolved.Could someone guide me on how to configure the extension or VSCode itself to display MDN references in a different language? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so? It looks all english in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-custom-data/blob/main/web-data/data/browsers.css-data.json and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-custom-data/blob/main/web-data/data/browsers.html-data.json.